# Is there way to update modified on, created on and created by fields in CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, kingswaysoft

I need to update modifiedon, createdon, modifiedby in CRM using SSIS via kingswaysoft. Is it possible? Because right now kingswaysoft is not showing these fields for mapping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In regards to these special fields, please check below:

•   **createdon**: create-only field, this field is only available for *create* operation (**Create** or **Upsert** action in the destination component). You would need to map your existing created date column from the source to the **overriddencreatedon** field in the CRM Destination component. Behind the scenes, the created date would get passed to the createdon field. NOTE that the overriddencreatedon field is NOT updatable, so you should provide the value when you create the record.

•   **modifiedon**: modifiedon field is not supported as the field is designed to be an auditing field, CRM platform does not allow to write to this field directly through web service API. However, it is possible to use a new custom field to receive the value and use CRM plugin code to inject the value to the **modifiedon** field, but this does require coding and some extra configuration. Generally speaking, there isn’t really much value migrating the **modifiedon** field, as it changes as soon as the record is touched in the new system.

•   **modifiedby**: update-only field, this field is only available for update operation (**Update** or **Upsert** action). When **Upsert** action is used, the **modifiedby** field would show up only if the **Batch Size = 1**. And it would only work if the **Upsert** action is identified as update because this column is NOT creatable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the most perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on-premise, you could still update the modified on and modified by directly with SQL. One of my client did not want to loose this information after the migration and it worked for us. It is not recommended by Microsoft, but as long as you test very well your process, it can be done. Thought, outside of a migration context, I would not recommend this.